# Does the rule $P * A = PAP^t$ define an operation of $GL_n$ on the set of n × n matrices.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Does the rule $P * A = PAP^t$ define an operation of $GL_n$ on the set of n × n matrices.

Wouldn't this just be taking the conjugate of an n x n matrix? Since the general linear group is a group of invertible matrices, $PAP^t$ should be a valid operation right?

Comment: Just try to check the definition of an action of a group.

Comment: is $P\in GL_n$ as well as $A$?

Comment: @Avitus I'm assuming they are if P and A are to define and operation on GLn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this defines a left-action of the general linear group, as is easily verified. And no, this would not just be taking conjugates of a matrix (whatever you mean by this). Rather this is the natural way $GL(n,K)$ acts on bilinear forms on $K^n$, with a form $f$ represented by the matrix of values $(f(e_i,e_j))_{i,j=1,\ldots,n}$, where $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ is the standard basis of$~K^n$.